# Equation label and align

Tags: tables, equations, lyx, labels

I'm using Lyx and I have problem with equations. I would like to add label to equation, but somehow I can't add label if formula is in table or float. Ok, I can take them outside and then I can label them. But(!), then I can't move the equations to left. Tried everything.

The best would be, if I can keep equations in table, so I can adjust them easily. The result should be same as the last three equations with label. 
/poor English

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the code that gives rise to the screenshot you've posted.

Comment: Inline math placed in a `tabular` has no number and therefore cannot be referenced. There are probably better ways of doing whatever it is you're trying though, could you explain in more detail what you want? If you want all displayed equations to be left aligned, go to Document --> Settings --> Documentclass, and add `fleqn` to the custom class options.